# Multiple regression equations

Tags: r, regression, stata, spss

Is there a way that I can run 100 different regressions together and get the output of all equations together in a table format?
Any software will work.
I need to find growth rates of 100 commodities using log-linear model. So I have 100 equations with dependent variable being ln(value of exports) and independent variables being time (0 to 30).
So running regression individually for 100 equations is lot of manual work. 
I just require the coefficients of t for all the 100 equations. Any way to shorten the time spent doing so?

Comment: Yes. But we need more detail about what you're trying to do. 100 different data sets?  100 different response variables with the same predictors? 100 different predictors with the same response variable?  And it would be nice if you gave us some evidence about what you've tried, so far, to find the answer for this problem yourself.

Comment: For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169587/regression-of-variables-in-a-dataframe)  talks about running regressions for lots of variables in R; once you had a list of regression models, `sapply(modelList,coef)` would give you a combined table of results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226194/stata-combining-coefficients-standard-errors-from-several-regressions-in-a-sing?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, assuming you have a data frame `commodity_data` in R with each commodity as a different column:

```
n <- ncol(commodity_data)
logslopes <- numeric(n)
tvec <- 0:(nrow(n)-1)
for (i in 1:n) {
  m <- lm(log(commodity_data[,i]) ~ tvec)
  slope <- coef(m)["tvec"]
  logslopes[i] <- slope
}
```

There are slicker ways of doing this, but this one should work fine.